# submission page error in my website on form for submit file but some time the mail come as follows

Tags: php

In my website on form for submit file but some time the mail come as follows

```
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Telephone:
Courntry:
How did you find us?:
Title:
Corresponding Author:
File Name:
```

But all the fields in the form are mandatary.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You should put here code which you have tried for mail and form.

Comment: Please, read before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask